# how to limit the length my array in state that holds the messages I'm getting from my data in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

So I'm using a pub/sub model that listens to published message from another client as they are sending in real-time, and I'm storing those messages on my component's state object as an array, and I keep adding them as they come in. I'm displaying the data in a chart but I was wondering how I could limit the amount of messages that state stores, say to maybe like 50? was thinking about using sliceshould i be mutating state to remove items also?

should I put an if condition in my ComponentDidMount method that checks state like this?

```
  if(this.state.data.length > 50) {
    this.setState({ data: this.state.slice(-50) })
  }
```

Just trying to see what a good approach would be to limiting the number of message so state doesn't have like 50,000 objects in it. Thanks

Edit:

Per Asymons comment, I changed it to look like this. And thank you so much your comment was so helpful. I just have one more question re: the last part you mentionned about reducing re-renders. Does this code satisfy that part, because I am very much concerned about performance so I would like to reduce re-renders as much as possible, thanks again.

```
componentDidMount() {

client.on('message', (topic, payload, packet) => {
  console.log('topic: ', topic);

  const parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload);
  if (parsedPayload.type !== 'pub') {
    return null;
  }
  const voltage = Math.trunc(parsedPayload.data.data.voltage);
  const pressure = Math.trunc(parsedPayload.data.data.air_pressure);
  const humidity = Math.trunc(parsedPayload.data.data.air_humidity);
  const temperature = Math.trunc(parsedPayload.data.data.air_temperature);
  const message = {
    time: moment().format('LT'),
    temperature,
    humidity,
    voltage,
    pressure,
    parsedPayload,
    topic,
  }
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    // create an array that holds objects with my data and push the 
    // message object as it comes in into the array
    const messages = [...prevState.messages]
    messages.push(message)
    if (prevState.messages.length > 20) {
      messages.pop()
      return {
        messages,
      };
    } else {
        return {
          messages,
        };
    }
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Where and how do you get the data from? You would truncate that right after you received data from the external API and right before you've `setState` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target where the data comes in from.

So in your componentDidMount wherever your network request is, you either request the amount of data (look into pagination) or get the whole payload and filter the data as it comes in. So in your case, filter it initially.

You said you're doing a pub/sub model so you'll have some data trickling in, that's fine. Shift your focus from slicing the whole thing to treating the data structure as a queue. Push items in and pop them when the size is above 50 or whatever your limit is. So the data would go into the state like a pipeline.

In order to reduce re-renders, copy your this.state.data into some variable, mutate that variable and then update the state with that mutated variable.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that is so helpful. This is what my componentDidMount function looks like right now is this what you meant?

Comment: Ok so it looks like after a little bit and research and your advice that I need to push items in then instead of the pop() method because that removes items from the end I used the shift() method to get rid of the first item in the array. again thanks

Comment: the way you have it now works if you're expecting one message at a time. If you had multiple messages at a time coming in, you would copy your state, map over the list of messages that came in, and did individual push/pops THEN you would set the state. Under the assumption that one message comes in at a time, what you have is fine :)